Nuxt - Component is already mounted, please use $fetch instead
I have this code
const redirectToPayment = async () => {
  const { data } = await useAsyncQuery(
    createCheckoutMutation,
    { variantId: product.value.productByHandle.variants.edges[0].node.id}
  );

  window.location.href = data.value.checkoutCreate.checkout.webUrl;
}

I am getting the next warning

[nuxt] [useAsyncData] Component is already mounted, please use $fetch instead. See https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching

I've been searching and reading and it seems the solution it's here, but I can't make it work in my example.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks
Edit/update from @Connor answer
I have tried moving the request outside de click (event handler) and I still receive the same warning
const data = await $fecth(
    createCheckoutMutation,
    { variantId: product.value.productByHandle.variants.edges[0].node.id}
  );


useAsyncData (and by extension useAsyncQuery) is a composable, which means it can only be called at the top level of a setup function. You cannot call it within an event handler.
When making requests within an event handler in Nuxt, $fetch is the correct approach.
You can read more about data fetching in Nuxt here.
I'm not familiar with Nuxt Apollo, but what you probably want to do is call useApollo in your setup function to get a handle on an apollo client and use that client in your handler function.

I have edited and updated my question, answering @Connor

If you are still receiving the same error, you are probably still using useAsyncQuery/useAsyncData

Thank you Connor, I think  the issue could be on the mutation, I'm debugging it looking for it. Thanks

It was a problem with @nuxtjs/apollo version
I was using "alpha.14"
The working one it's
"@nuxtjs/apollo": "5.0.0-alpha.5"
